# parity of function over general field

Tags: abstract-algebra

we know over $\mathbb{R}$, the only function that is both even and odd is the zero function. My question is: what happens if the function is not over $\mathbb{R}$, but over some other field? Field of characteristic $0$ or $p$? How about a finite field?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by looking at the proof of what you say in $\Bbb R$.  If $f$ is both even and odd then for any $x$ we have
$$f(x)=-f(-x)=-f(x)\quad\Rightarrow\quad 2f(x)=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad f(x)=0\ .$$
This uses only the field axioms, the definitions of even and odd functions, and the assumption in the last step that we can divide by $2$: that is, the assumption that $2\ne0$.  Therefore the same is true if the **codomain** of $f$ is any field, finite or infinite, of characteristic ${}\ne2$.

If the codomain is a field of characteristic $2$ then
$$f(x)=-f(-x)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad f(x)=f(-x)\ ,$$
so that even and odd mean the same thing.  There will be non-zero functions which are both even and odd, for example the identity function (as long as the domain of $f$ is the same as the codomain).

Comment: Thanks, David! This is such a through answer.